# How to customize the robot framework test output?

Tags: listener, robotframework

I'm trying to figure out how to customize the output of robot test script with a listener. I am trying to use the following listener:

```
from robot.api import logger

class TestListener:

    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.pass_count = 0
        self.fail_count = 0
        self.skip_count = 0
        self.error_count = 0
        self.total_count = 0

    def end_test (self, name, attributes):
        if attributes['status'] == 'PASS':
            self.pass_count = self.pass_count + 1
        else:
            self.fail_count = self.fail_count + 1
        self.total_count = self.total_count + 1

    def close(self):
        logger.console("%d tests total, %d passed, %d failed" % (self.total_count,self.pass_count,self.fail_count))
```

but somehow when I run the pybot, I'm getting the following output:

```
% pybot --listener listen.py --output NONE --log NONE --report NONE --quiet --exitonfailure --outputdir NONE test.robot

[ WARN ] Listener 'listener.py' uses deprecated API version 1. Switch to API version 2 instead.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
108   980  108   980    0     0   1677      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 25789
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 17125  100 17125    0     0  55405      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  229k
```

I'm wondering why there are still statistical data shown above even when "--quiet" mode is used, and why the output from the logger.console in listener is not shown.

Any help is very much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The output you see is likely the output from a keyword which doesn't go through the logging mechanism. For example, your keyword might print directly to stdout or to /dev/tty.